Is it possible to define hierarchical tags using conditional logic in Org?
Is it possible to define hierarchical tags in Org using conditional logic? For example, suppose the hierarchy I want is as follows.

work

work1
work2


home

home1
home2



I would like to achieve two things: (1) for the first-level tags work and home to be mutually exclusive, and (2) the second-level tags work1 and work2 (resp. home1 and home2) to be available only if the first-level tag is work (resp. home).
The Org manual (here) and the Org mode compact guide (here) explain how to do the first. So I have the following code.
(setq org-tag-alist
  '((:startgroup)
    ("work" . ?w)
    ("home" . ?h)
    (:endgroup)))

For the second-level tags I have tried this:
(setq org-tag-alist
  '((:startgroup)
    ("work" . ?w)
    ("home" . ?h)
    (:endgroup)
    ("work1")
    ("work2")
    ("home1")
    ("home2")))

But all four second-level tags are then available under both first-level tags. Is there a way to do what I want?

My read of the documentation you linked is you define the tags like this:
(setq org-tag-alist '((:startgrouptag)
                      ("Context")
                      (:grouptags)
                      ("work")
                      ("home")
                      (:endgrouptag)
                      (:startgroup)
                      ("work")
                      (:grouptags)
                      ("work1")
                      ("work2")
                      (:endgroup)
                      (:startgroup)
                      ("home")
                      (:grouptags)
                      ("home1")
                      ("home2")
                      (:endgroup)))

I am not sure this gets you what you want though. for example, with this, if I try to add a tag to a headline, it doesn't seem to limit what tags are available by completion, and it doesn't prevent adding mutually exclusive tags. I am not sure if that is expected behavior or not.

Hi John. Thank you for your answer. But, no, I don't think it does the trick. I can make the first-level tags mutually exclusive by replacing :startgrouptag with :startgroup. But don't see a way of restricting the available second-level tags. I suspect that conditional logic just isn't supported.
